# Phonegap 3.3.0 Plugins not working with Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I know, this question has to be boring for you guys by now, but I can't figure out, where I made my mistake...

I'm trying to use the InAppBrowser from PhoneGap itself (https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1169) and this E-Mail Composer (https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/705).
When I build them locally, everything works just fine, but I need to build them with Phonegap build.

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.crm20700153" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>CRM2.0</name>
  <description>
        TODO
    </description>
  <author email="example@example.de" href="http://example.de">
      Mr. Smith
    </author>
    <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.1" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
</widget>
```

The project was created with the Ionic CLI and runs on Phonegap version 3.3.0

Note: Yes, I have used google etc. but I realy haven't found anything that helps me.
If I was too dumb, feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: First of all, Phonegap's latest version is 3.6.3. You can try running on that version.Secondly; not all the Phonegap plugins are supported by Phonegap Build. Go check the https://build.phonegap.com/plugins page for supported plugins.

Comment: The plugins are supported and the problem wasn't the version.
I found the problem and I'm about to fix it. The answer will follow when I'm finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I promised, I'll answer my own question now.

The problem was, that Ionic uses Cordova, not Phonegap, so I had to move the config.xml from the root directory to the www directory, otherwise PhonegapBuild wouldn't recognize it.
I also had to add

```
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
```

to

```
<widget id="com.ionicframework.crm20700153" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"  xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

That's all, now you can add plugins like you would do it when you only use Phonegap.